# Image upload with selenium webdriver not working

Tags: selenium-webdriver, image-upload

I am not able to automate image upload with selenium webdriver.
I have tried with AutoIT and Robot class as well , But its not working.
I have also tried with different options suggested on stackoverflow but not working for me...

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"addSampleImg\"]")).sendKeys("D:\\Test11");
```

Any other option to resolve?

Comment: Share the HTML code & exception trace.

Comment: Update the question with relevant _HTML_, _tried with different options_ trials and error stack trace

Answer (score 0):

You should have to include the file name as an argument in sendKeys().

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"addSampleImg\"]")).sendKeys("D:\Test11\Your file name with extension")
```

For ex.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"addSampleImg\"]")).sendKeys("D:\Test11\Sample.jpeg");
```

Hope it will work then.